# installments with the exact sum

Tags: php, numbers, sum, parcel

is there any way to accurately calculate the installments? remembering that the sum of these parcels shall be the total value of the? I usually do a loop which will split and burn in the database, if the number of parcels is 4, I record four records .. but I want to know if there is any way that I can piecemeal parts that final sum is accurate, as `X = 500, P = 3`, if I dividor `(500 / 3)`, `166.666` will give ... but the result is that I hope to get something like: `X = 500, P = 3, p¹ = 150: p² = 150, p³ = 200`

Legend: **X = Order Value**, **P = Number of Parcels.** , `p¹, p², p³ = parcel 1, 2 and 3`

Remember, the value of the order, will never be exact, I get `2598.90`, `2038.80` .. etc.

Comment: It's a little tough to understand what you're trying to accomplish _exactly_. Could you please explain further? Perhaps add a code sample?

Comment: Hello, with a code I can not not, I have no idea where to start, I'm trying to get the parcels on which the sum of these is equal to the value of the order

Comment: "the value of the order, will never be exact,"...but you still want to have a natural number (integer) solution for your parcels?

Comment: Not exactly, the value of the parcels may contain decimal, but the sum has to be EXACT

Comment: Are you trying to determine the set of all combinations of [p1, p2, p3] = X? Or is your problem that you are trying to compare the equality of floating point numbers (which are by nature inexact)?

Comment: Are you simply saying that you're running into floating point precision issues? (Just trying to clarify, because as @rdlowrey suggested, your question is unclear to me at the moment).

Comment: well, is this I have a number X (order value), this number divided by the number of parts, will not always give accurate, in this case, I want the sum of all parcels is just X, is like a partitioning, but with no fixed values​​.

Comment: Are you trying to do installment (payout) calculator?

Comment: Yes, @ajreal, solved the problem with you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is my guess

```
$total = 23419.97;     // total amount
$total_parcel = 24;    // total parcel

// average parcle
$avg_parcel = floor($total / $total_parcel); // nearest integer;

// value for each parcel
$parcels = array_fill(0, $total_parcel, $avg_parcel);

// change last parcel value
// so, sum of all parcel = total
$parcels[$total_parcel-1] = $total-(($total_parcel-1)*$avg_parcel);
```

Comment: Warning: array_fill() [function.array-fill]: Number of elements must be positive